pip3 install dlib: fails, getting "Failed Building Wheel for Dlib" Error
Edit 2: Solution
Fully reinstalling WSL using this (https://superuser.com/a/1755410/1210833) link, along with apt install cmake and pip install dlib as the first things on this new WSL install solved the issue. Pip installing cmake is what broke it, and I've learnt to be careful whether I use pip or apt in the future.
Beginning of Original Post:
I'm trying to install a facial recognition package provided to me to get a grip for machine learning. I've been provided the code that handles the training and recognition, all I need to do (for now) is get everything installed correctly.
The project I'm setting up has the following dependencies:
cmake
python-git
imutils
opencv-python
face-recognition
(Note: I'm using Ubuntu via WSL on a Windows 10 machine.)
In order to install a sub dependency of opencv-python, dlib, I have to install cmake.
Edit:
I've opted for fully reinstalling WSL2 (Ubuntu distro) using this (https://superuser.com/a/1755410/1210833) process.
The very first thing I did was install pip using sudo apt install pip (PIP version 22.0.2; Python version 3.10.12). Following that, I did pip install cmake. The output is as follows:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writable
Collecting cmake
  Using cached cmake-3.29.3-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (26.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: cmake
  WARNING: The scripts cmake, cpack and ctest are installed in '/home/dydro/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed cmake-3.29.3

From there, I added /home/dydro/.local/bin to PATH in .bashrc. Uninstalling and reinstalling cmake shows the same message as above, just without the warning about cmake not being in PATH.
Next, I ran pip install dlib. The following error occurred:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/dydro/.local/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib

The only things I've done on this WSL instance are the previously mentioned steps. Regardless of the reinstall, I'm getting the same sort of error as I've gotten before.
I'm wondering if the issue comes from either the distro, or the fact that cmake installed to /home/dydro/.local/bin/ rather than /usr/bin/.
OLD POST:
I am to run pip install -r requirements.txt  to install everything.
When I run said command, I get the following output:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.29.3)
Collecting python-git
  Using cached python_git-2018.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting imutils
  Using cached imutils-0.5.4.tar.gz (17 kB)
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.82-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (38.8 MB)
Collecting face-recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: send2trash in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-git->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.8.3)
Collecting numpy>=1.17.0
  Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (15.8 MB)
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0
  Using cached face_recognition_models-0.3.0.tar.gz (100.1 MB)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (8.1.7)
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from Click>=6.0->face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.4.6)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for imutils, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for face-recognition-models, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' 'c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\dydro\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqow92qpz'
       cwd: C:\Users\dydro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k9cq3vc\dlib_91901d12868c452084288c91764ddb2b
  Complete output (6 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext

  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -0p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

There are two notable parts. First, confirmation I have CMake installed and second, the actual error message:

"Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.29.3)"
"CMake must be installed to build dlib"

Install of CMake using pip install cmake is in /mnt/c/Python39/site-packages/cmake/ (in Ubuntu) or C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cmake (in File Explorer). CMake is added to my Windows PATH via C:\Program Files\CMake\bin (a manual install of CMake, described later).
Additionally, I have instances of CMake in my local Ubuntu install. Specifically,
/usr/local/bin/cmake* (an executable)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cmake/ (a folder)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cmake/ (a folder)
/usr/home/dydro/.local/bin/cmake/ (a folder)

Things I have tried:

Running sudo apt-get install cmake and sudo apt install cmake from WSL.
Running pip install cmake and sudo pip install cmake from WSL.
Uninstalling and reinstalling pip.
Uninstalling and reinstalling CMake (via pip).
Manually installing CMake from https://cmake.org/download/ and downloading the Windows x64 Installer. This install of CMake is the one added to my Windows PATH.
Manually changing my PYTHONPATH (in Ubuntu) to look at folders I know, for a fact, have a cmake folder in them.

Very interestingly, running sudo pip install -r requirements.txt provides a slightly different message than the one above:
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.29.3)
Collecting python-git (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached python_git-2018.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting imutils (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached imutils-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opencv-python (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.82-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting face-recognition (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
Collecting send2trash (from python-git->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.21.5)
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 (from face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached face_recognition_models-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Click>=6.0 (from face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting dlib>=19.7 (from face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Pillow (from face-recognition->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Using cached python_git-2018.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Using cached opencv_python-4.10.0.82-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (62.5 MB)
Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Using cached pillow-10.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

The contents of /usr/local/bin/ are six executables, cmake*  cpack*  ctest*  pip*  pip3*  pip3.10*. It would make sense if when dlib calls the executable /usr/local/bin/cmake, which imports the directory cmake, that it wouldn't find said directory within /usr/local/bin. However--and correct me if I'm wrong--but I believe pip should be searching through at least one of the previously mentioned locations where the cmake folder is found.
Particularly interesting is that when I throw a copy of the cmake folder into the /usr/local/bin directory (as "cmake_test/") AND edit /usr/local/bin/cmake* to ONLY import cmake_test but NOT from cmake import cmake I can get around it not finding cmake. Which just ends up with another problem:
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/bin/cmake", line 6, in <module>
          import cmake_test
        File "/usr/local/bin/cmake_test/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
          cmake_files = distribution("cmake").files
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 969, in distribution
          return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 548, in from_name
          raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
      importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for cmake

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I interpret this to mean it's trying to find folders or files called "cmake" but because I renamed the folder to "cmake_test", it's screwing up. Alternatively it could be that it's still failing to find where my cmake files are installed, meaning I'm basically back at square one.
There's only two conclusions I'm drawing from all of this:

Given python and pip are installed at the Windows level, they report I have it installed on the Windows level (when pip install -r requirements.txt initially cheks for and successfully finds cmake in c:\python39\lib\site-packages). BUT the actual complilation is happening at the WSL level (as evident by the crash traceback coming from /usr/local/bin/), and that is throwing everything out of wack. Like telling someone they're in an open field when they're really in a windy, 4D, optical illusion kind of room.
My CMake libraries are simply in the wrong places, presumably meaning that my PATH and PYTHONPATH env's cannot find it and link stuff together.

As an additional note, I've tried to do this on two machines now. Both using WSL, though the other machine being on Windows 11 rather than my current rig using Windows 10. The other machine was having the exact same issue, though I've tested less extensively on that one.
I have looked into potential fixes and causes for this, however nothing as of yet has helped. I'm seeing more people stumped and stuck without an answer than with one. Hopefully, though, there's something simple I have missed or some ideas I haven't thought of that would be good to try.
TIA

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

the bot's messages need to be tweaked. this post doesn't actually contain any code or config, just error messages, arising from trying to install some package off of pypi

@OP you should simplify this though. [mre]. the issue comes from trying to install dlib. it's doing that from a .tar.gz, i.e. from source. all the other stuff you're doing is not relevant to the issue, so strip it out of the question. DO make sure the situation you present is consistent.

note: I have a fairly fresh WSL2 Ubuntu on my system. pip3 install dlib took a few minutes to build, but without issues. I've got python 3.10 and the install finished with Created wheel for dlib: filename=dlib-19.24.4-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=4081620 sha256=...

I don't have a /usr/local/bin/cmake but /usr/bin/cmake and /bin/cmake (3.22.1). I also don't have a "cmake" python package, nor was that installed at any point as a dependency of dlib. IDK what you did to your system, but that's probably the issue, your having a /usr/local/bin/cmake. it acts like a python script...

I have dlib on Linux Mint and I also don't have module cmake. Shell command which cmake shows me /usr/bin/cmake, and  file $(which cmake) shows that it is not Python script but LF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64,  ... - so it could be created with C/C++ language. Maybe I don't need cmake because when it installs it then it show that it uses precompiled dlib-19.24.4-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl . Using Google I found something like this: Dlib compiled binary (.whl) for Python 3.7-3.12 and Windows x64

@ChristophRackwitz I have provided an edit at the top of the post clarifying and (hopefully) providing a reproducible way of causing the issue. I now have cmake only existing in the .local/bin/ directory.
Thank you for providing advice on my post. Should I delete the old, non-applicable portions or simply leave it?

DO NOT "pip3 install cmake". that's wrong. that is how you destroyed your system last time. pip is for python stuff, not for system level stuff. if your system lacks cmake, apt install cmake. also cmake may not even be required, unless the pip3 install dlib specifically tells you.

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you so much, that solved the issue! If you know and are willing to explain, why would pip to install cmake brick my system's ability to install dlib? Conversely, should any system level stuff always be installed using apt? TIA

pip and apt are entirely, ENTIRELY, different things. they are not interchangeable.
